# Failed to install app error: Invalid Bundle - No Apple Watch Binary

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I'm trying to develop an extension of my app for the Apple Watch.

Instead of install the app on the watch, I have this error:

> AppName Failed to install AppName, error: Invalid Bundle - No Apple Watch Binary

In my info.plist files...

For the extension, I have:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.AppName.watchkitextension</string>
<key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.AppName.watchkitapp</string>
```

For the WatchKit app, I have:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key
    <string>com.mycompany.AppName.watchkitapp</string>
<key>WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.AppName</string>
```

And for my app, I have:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.AppName</string>
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the "Executable file" in the WatchKit app's info.plist.

I had changed the name of my executable file and had the same issue.

Comment: It's a possible explanation. Indeed, I work on 2 projects with the same settings. One for test the watchkit frameworks, and the other project is the real project. I didn't check the executable file. I will try this as soon as possible. Thank you

Comment: Where do you find your explicit "Executable File" name? I can't seem to have any luck with this solution

Comment: Try adding it using the + in the watchkit's plist. It should come up in autocomplete as you're typing (case sensitive: "Executable file").

Comment: An addendum: I continued to have issues with installation despite getting past this error. My watchkit app was stuck on "Installing..." forever within the iPhone watch app. I ended up fixing these issues by going through my product names/bundle names and ensuring that none of them were the same.

Comment: what i mean what, what is your executable file name if you don't use $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

Comment: ah, check under the Products folder.

Comment: Any update here? Im experiencing the same issue with Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: When I try to change the executable file name I can't even build the project anymore without getting an Xcode error.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, what worked for me was changing the "Executable file" in *extension's* plist to the extension name (the name show under products, minus the .appex)

Answer (score 16):

This error plagued me for about 7 hours then I restarted my watch out of desperation and the error went away.

Comment: This solution only worked on 1 project for me. The other app continues to have the same error

Answer (score 4):

I was plagued with this error for hours. For me, the problem was that my WatchKit Extension's Deployment Target was set to an iOS version higher than my phone's. I simply changed it to match my device's version and it worked perfectly. [image]

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was fixed by adding the watch app to my iOS target's Embed Watch Content section.

I'm using Xcode 7 and watchOS 2.0. It was building fine on the device, but the simulator was giving me this error.

Steps:

1. Find your iOS target
2. Click Build Phases
3. Ensure your watch app (.app) is included in "Target Dependencies" and "Embed Watch Content"

Comment: This was the fix for me, I had previously removed the watch app from the build.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of these solutions worked for me, however I noticed that by default, my WatchKit App required iOS 8.3, and my phone was running iOS 8.2. Updating the OS to 8.3 solved my problem. It may seem like an obvious solution, but I thought I would share for anyone who could share my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got it when building app for WatchOS2. I fixed by setting the schemes like this:

The Watch Extension Scheme builds
    3 Target: iPhone (2 dependencies) + Extension (no dependencies) + Watch App

```
Running Extension Scheme on iPhone simulator -> works!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an **Info.plist** configuration error. The `Bundle identifier` was different to the `NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> WKAppBundleIdentifier`.

Setting the same value fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Resets of watch/xcode/iphone doesn't help sometimes, as it described in other answer.

One more case to solve this:
This error appears, when I **change iPhone language of my iPhone** to not English (in my case - Russian) language.
When I set back English - everything start works as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

- The bundle id of iOS app is **prefix** of watch app & extension' bundle id.
- Value of `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` in Info.plist of your watch app matches bundle id of your iOS app.
- iOS app, watch app & extension should signed by the same cert.
- There must be a build phase in iOS app target:

  - Destination: Products Directory
  - Subpath: `$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Watch`
  - Click +, add your watch app target.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in the Bundle Display name in the info.plist.Default is blank,there will be an alert.(Xcode 7.3)

[image]