# invalid bundle - no apple watch binary (Unable to debug WatchOS App on simulator or device)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm unable to Run Apple Watch App either in Simulator or can not even debug in real device, after waiting few seconds after building+installing build it is giving below error:

**"invalid bundle no apple watch binary"**

I've tried different possible solutions/options based on Apple Developer Form and StackOverflow, however i could not find any solution.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4200

[Failed to install app error: Invalid Bundle - No Apple Watch Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29972534)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497555

I also developed an other app for WatchOS1 and it is working fine, that app was created using Xcode 6.4 and also working fine on Xcode 7.2

I guess there is any issue in Xcode 7.2 to add WatchOS Target, as my old created apple watch target is working fine. Is there any solution or workaround for it?

Comment: hey man, any luck?

Comment: I did not get any response from Apple.

Try to double check Apple WatchKit App and AppleWatchKitExtension that it has no leading space.  If there is any space then remove space. My App started working after i tried to check all things step by step. Not sure what was exact issue.  Also try validate build from Apple Store build validator, It might give some errors of WatchKit while submitting build.